# MySQL - Datas all included in larger data set

Tags: php, mysql

So I have 2 tables:

```
user_selection (id, user_id, fiche_id)
fiche (id, title, ...)
```

(fiche = sheet)

I have a research request which gives me some fiche ids

```
SELECT fiche.*, IF(fiche.fiche_type_id = 2,fiche.instance,fiche_type_texte.type_texte) AS type_texte, IF(fiche.fiche_type_id = 2,CONCAT(fiche.affaire," - ", fiche.titre),fiche.titre) AS titre, IF(fiche.fiche_type_id = 1,fiche.date_publication,fiche.date_texte) AS date_publication
FROM enviroveille_bascule.fiche
LEFT JOIN enviroveille_bascule.fiche_type_texte ON(fiche.fiche_type_texte_id = fiche_type_texte.id)
LEFT JOIN enviroveille_bascule.fiche_x_keyword ON(fiche_x_keyword.fiche_id = fiche.id)
LEFT JOIN enviroveille_bascule.fiche_x_theme ON(fiche_x_theme.fiche_id = fiche.id)
LEFT JOIN enviroveille_bascule.fiche_echeance ON(fiche_echeance.fiche_id = fiche.id)
LEFT JOIN enviroveille_bascule.fiche_x_activite ON(fiche_x_activite.fiche_id = fiche.id) LEFT JOIN enviroveille_bascule.fiche_x_nomenclature ON(fiche_x_nomenclature.fiche_id = fiche.id)
WHERE 1 = 1
AND fiche_echeance.fiche_echeance_type_id IN(2)
GROUP BY fiche.id
```

I'd like to know if all results from my research query is in the user selection.

So I tried :

```
// fiche_ids is an array of fiche.id resulting from research request 
SELECT COUNT(*) AS nb
FROM " . $this->bdd . $this->table_user_selection . "
WHERE user_id = '" . $user->datas_user['id'] . "'
AND fiche_id IN ('" . implode("','", $fiche_ids) . "')

    if($ds['nb'] == count($fiche_ids) && count($fiche_ids) > 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

That works well

Problem is that I have some research request giving 10K+ results.
And I have to do it several time on the same page, which makes server lags.

Is there a easy way to know if all my results are in my selection?
Note that selection may contain more fiche_id than the research result.

The best would be to be able do this in one SQL request.

Comment: off topic, i can't understand how is possible to not get lost using db field names like this **fiche_echeance_type_id** :D can't you call it **this_is_a_db_field_his_name_is_db_field** ? :D joking ;)

Comment: @okok Have you considered the possibility the in the OP's native language (which seems to be something other than English) these names actually mean something?

Comment: @AleksG eheh , sure i considered, mine would be just a ironic suggestion to use shorter db field names ;)

Comment: fiche_echeance_type_id is a foreing key to fiche_echeance_type.id